# How to display data as 3D bars/stories on Map using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, 3d, visualization

I am a beginner in ASP.NET.I am researching on 3D data visualisation on Google Maps using ASP.NET. I have integrated the map with web site. Now, I have to show data as bars/stories on the map. More like the Microsoft's  [Geoflow](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/news/features/geoflow_data_viz-041113.aspx). Please, guide me. I want to know the pre-requisites(tools etc) and possible procedure to implement the concept.

Answer (score 0):

i never worked with these but u can still try the 3D programming libraries

http://www.lutanho.net/svgvml3d/index.html

http://www.garybeene.com/3d/3d-vml.htm